# Use jQuery method on loaded elements

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a website where elements are dynamically loaded with .load()

Some of these elements have an edit_area class, for use with jeditable (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

loadMe.html

```
<div class="edit_area" id="news">
    Content to be loaded
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#loadArea').load('loadMe.html');
$('.edit_area').editable('save.php', { 
    type      : 'textarea',
    cancel    : 'Cancel',
    submit    : 'OK',
    indicator : '<img src="loaderimage.gif">',
    tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
});
```

Since these elements are being dynamically loaded, the .ediable() method is not being bound to them, how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#loadArea").load('loadMe.html', function () {
    $('.edit_area').editable('save.php', {
        //etc.
```

If you do `.editiable` in the *callback* from `.load`, the elements must be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loadArea').load('loadMe.html', function()
{
    $('.edit_area').editable('save.php', { 
      type      : 'textarea',
      cancel    : 'Cancel',
      submit    : 'OK',
      indicator : '<img src="loaderimage.gif">',
      tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
    });
});
```

Comment: `.load` does not return a deferred (for some reason)

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's np, I'm just updating so that I don't leave incorrect code here. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback from the load event you can use the 'find' method to find the necessary child elements you would like to apply 'editable' to.

Answer (score 0):

since your elements are dynamically loaded they don't necessarily exist when your code is called.

take a look at .delegate

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/